# Running init container on deployment update

Tags: kubernetes

What triggers init container to be run?

Will editing deployment descriptor (or updating it with helm), for example, changing the image tag, trigger the init container?

Will deleting the pod trigger the init container?

Will reducing replica set to null and then increasing it trigger the init container?

Is it possible to manually trigger init container?

Comment: The only way to run an init container is by creating a new pod, but both updating a deployment and deleting a deployment-managed pod should trigger that.  Can you give a more complete example of a case that doesn't work?

Comment: @DavidMaze I thought the container wasn't launched because the file permissions hasn't changed. Now I've added debugging to my script, and I've changed the question. The real issue is probably the emptyDir.

Comment: Could you describe your issue in a detailed way ? You posted actually 5 different questions and in a comment you are referring to another thing. In your description there are not enough details to recreate and debug your problem.

Comment: @mario please forget the comment, my question is, when is the initContainer invoked, because it's not clear to me in official documentation.

Answer (score 8):

> What triggers init container to be run?

Basically `initContainers` are run every time a `Pod`, which has such containers in its definition, is created and reasons of creation of a `Pod` can be quite different. As you can read in official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) ***init containers*** *run before app containers in a `Pod`* and they *always run to completion*. *If a Pod’s init container fails, Kubernetes repeatedly restarts the Pod until the init container succeeds.* So one of the things that trigger starting an `initContainer` is, among others, previous failed attempt of starting it.

> Will editing deployment descriptor (or updating it with helm), for
>   example, changing the image tag, trigger the init container?

Yes, basically every change to `Deployment` definition that triggers creation/re-creation of `Pods` managed by it, also triggers their `initContainers` to be run. It doesn't matter if you manage it by helm or manually. Some slight changes like adding for example a new set of labels to your `Deployment` don't make it to re-create its `Pods` but changing the container `image` for sure causes the controller (`Deployment`, `ReplicationController` or `ReplicaSet`) to re-create its `Pods`.

> Will deleting the pod trigger the init container?

No, deleting a `Pod` will not trigger the init container. If you delete a `Pod` which is not managed by any controller it will be simply gone and no automatic mechanism will care about re-creating it and running its `initConainers`. If you delete a `Pod` which is managed by a controller, let's say a `replicaSet`, it will detect that there are less `Pods` than declared in its yaml definition and it will try to create such missing `Pod` to match the desired/declared state. So I would like to highlight it again that it is not the deletion of the `Pod` that triggers its `initContainers` to be run, but `Pod` creation, no matter manual or managed by the controller such as `replicaSet`, which of course can be triggered by manual deletion of the `Pod` managed by such controller.

> Will reducing replica set to null and then increasing it trigger the
>   init container?

Yes, because when you reduce the number of replicas to 0, you make the controller delete all `Pods` that fall under its management. When they are re-created, all their startup processes are repeated including running `initContainers` being part of such `Pods`.

> Is it possible to manually trigger init container?

As @David Maze already stated in his comment *The only way to run an init container is by creating a new pod, but both updating a deployment and deleting a deployment-managed pod should trigger that.* I would say it depends what you mean by the term *manually*. If you ask whether this is possible to trigger somehow an `initContainer` without restarting / re-creating a `Pod` - no, it is not possible. Starting `initContainers` is tightly related with `Pod` creation or in other words with its startup process.

Btw. all what you're asking in your question is quite easy to test. You have a lot of working examples in *kubernetes official docs* that you can use for testing different scenarios and you can also create simple `initContainer` by yourself e.g. using `busybox` image which only task is to `sleep` for the required number of seconds. Here you have some useful links from different k8s docs sections related to *initContainers*:

[Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

[Debug Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/)

[Configure Pod Initialization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/)